# Error in Shader Source

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I've got a problem with a shader program. It comunicates with messages:

Vertex info

(0) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $end at token

Fragment info

(0) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $end at token

It's my Shader Loading function. Probably in this function there is somelike error (?).

```
GLuint ConfigureShaders(string vsName, string fsName)
{
    // Utworz Shadery
    VS = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    FS = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Czytaj Shadery
    string LineBuffer;

    fstream VSFile(vsName.c_str(),ios::in);
    string VSSource;
    if(VSFile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(VSFile,LineBuffer))
            VSSource.append("\n"+LineBuffer);
        VSFile.close();
    }

    fstream FSFile(fsName.c_str(),ios::in);
    string FSSource;
    if(FSFile.is_open())
    {
        LineBuffer.clear();
        while(getline(FSFile,LineBuffer))
            FSSource.append("\n"+LineBuffer);
        FSFile.close();
    }

    GLint result;
    // int infoLogLength;
    // Wprowadz, Kompiluj i Sprawdz Shadery
    char const* VSSrc = VSSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,1,&VSSrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(VS);
    glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

  char VSErrMsg[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VS,1024,NULL,VSErrMsg);
    cout<<VSErrMsg<<endl;

    char const* FSSrc = FSSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,1,&FSSrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(FS);
  glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

  char FSErrMsg[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FS,1024,NULL,FSErrMsg);
    cout<<FSErrMsg<<endl;

    // Polacz Shadery
    GLuint Shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(Shader,VS);
    glAttachShader(Shader,FS);
    glLinkProgram(Shader);
    // Sprawdz Program
    glGetProgramiv(Shader,GL_LINK_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetProgramiv(Shader,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

    char PrgErrMsg[256];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(Shader,1024,NULL,PrgErrMsg);
    cout<<PrgErrMsg<<endl;

  // Kasuj Shadery
    glDeleteShader(VS);
    glDeleteShader(FS);
    return Shader;
}
```

Shader Sources are simple and seem to be good:

VS:

```
#version 400
layout(location=0) vec3 vertexPos;

void main()
{
  gl_Position.xyz = vertexPos;
  gl_Position.w = 1.0f;
}
```

FS:

```
#version 400

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
  color = vec3(0,0,1);
}
```

---

So error I have in that lines:

```
char const* VSSrc = VSSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,1,&VSSrc,NULL);
...
char const* FSSrc = FSSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,1,&FSSrc,NULL);
```

@datenwolf:

- Ok I understand that NULL in last parameter means NULL string
  terminator at the end of string with Shader Source. Why strings are
  not properly null terminated if I use c_str(), isn't string class
  reliable?
- Have I to pass FSource.size() to last parameter? How to properly cast
  it to (GLint*)?

[EDIT:]
I've got the errors:

```
char const* VSSrc = VSSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(VS,1,&VSSrc,NULL); // It Should be VS ID instead of GL_VERTEX_SHADER
...
char const* FSSrc = FSSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(FS,1,&FSSrc,NULL); // It Should be FS ID instead of GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
```

Problem in routine was using GL_VERTEX_SHADER and GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER as VS and FS IDs, those were undefined in program.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical error happening, if `glShaderSource` is called without length information and the strings are not properly null terminated. My recommendation is to pass both length information and add padding null bytes to the end of the string.